# A series of functions converges uniformly if the sequence of partial sums converges uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is there a proof or quick explanation for this statement:

A series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k(x)$ converges uniformly if the sequence of partial sums $s_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)$ converges uniformly.

I know that convergence of sequence of partial sums implies convergence of the series but I am not sure how to extend it to uniformity.

Comment: How you define "series converges uniformly" without partial sums?

Comment: @zkutch my book states: a sequence $f_n(x)$ of functions on a common domain $D$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$ if for all $\frac 1 m$, there exists $N$ such that for all $x \in D$, $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \frac 1 m$ if $n \geq N$ and then only states that "the definition of uniform convergence of a series of functions is analogous."

Comment: So, accordingly to your book, uniform convergence of partial sums is exactly uniform convergence of series, on given domain. It's definition.

Comment: @zkutch Sorry, I don't quite see how it is exactly uniform convergence of series though...? Actually I'm not quite sure what the analogous version they state is exactly: is it, for all $\frac 1 m$ ... $|\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x) - f(x)| < \frac 1 m$?

Comment: Yes. $f_n(x)$ in case of series is partial sums. For example John M.H. Olmsted - Advanced calculus-Prentice Hall (1961), page 444.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question of terminology/definitions. By definition, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ is the function $f(x)$ defined by the limit $\lim_N s_N(x)$ of partial sums. The sequence of functions $s_N(x)$ may or may not converge uniformly in $x$, but if it does, then we say the series defining $f(x)$ converges uniformly.